# Search for pattern and replace the line

Tags: regex, perl, bash

I am trying to search for a pattern,replace it with contents of another file and write this whole file to a new file. But I don't want to change the contents of the original file. I am trying to do this in parts, meaning, replace the pattern in the first run, write the whole thing to a different file and replace this pattern back to the original pattern. But for some reason, even my substitute and replace isn't working. The following is my perl code. Kindly throw some light if there is a better way to do this bash.

And the file I want to read is test.txt which has a lot of stuff. the one i want to modify and write to a different file would like this:

```
blah blah blah
blah blah PATTERN blah blah
blah blah blah
```

Now I want this to be exactly as is when I am done with it, but there should be another file test2.txt which looks like this:

```
blah blah blah
blah blah STUFF FROM TEST.TXT blah blah
blah blah blah
```

```
#!/usr/local/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
my @m;
my $filename = "test1.txt";
my $filename1 = "test2.txt";
open(WPR,"<",$filename);
@m=<WPR>;
close(WPR);
open(FPR,">>",$filename1);
while(<FPR>)
{
 s/PATTERN/@m/;
}
close(FPR);
```

Comment: Edit your question to show sample input from both files and the output you seek?

Comment: I just edited, I hope this helps in understanding my question.

Comment: *"And the file I want to read is test.txt which has a lot of stuff."*  You need to be more specific about what you mean by the term "stuff."

Comment: Oh, sorry. It means it has so many lines. Like:

one two three four five etc etc...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try something like this:

```
$ cat mainfile 
blah blah blah
blah blah PATTERN blah blah
blah blah blah
```

```
$ cat lookupfile 
this is my lookup file
```

```
$ text=$(<lookupfile)
```

```
$ sed "s/PATTERN/$text/" mainfile 
blah blah blah
blah blah this is my lookup file blah blah
blah blah blah
```

Answer (score 0):

Try slurping the content of the file you are reading into a scalar:

```
my $content = join('', <WPR>);
```

And then do your substitution with that scalar:

```
s/PATTERN/$content/;
```

Comment: It helped read the contents of the file but my substitution still isn't happening. Is there something that I am doing wrong?

Comment: Try starting with a much simpler substitution to see if that works. For example: `s/blah/THIS IS A TEST`; .

Answer (score 0):

You can try to solve it using a `one-liner`:

```
perl -pe '
    BEGIN { @d = do { local $/ = undef; open $fh, q|<|, shift; <$fh> }; chomp @d } 
    s/four/@d/
' test1.txt text2.txt
```

I process the first file in slurp mode and save all its content in an array. The `-p` switch processes the other one provided as argument line by line, so you can apply the regular expression to each line.

Assuming `text1.txt` with data:

```
new
data
```

And `text2.txt` with:

```
one
two
three
four
five
six
seven
four
nine
ten
```

It yields:

```
one
two
three
new
data
five
six
seven
new
data
nine
ten
```

Comment: But I need a different file that looks liek your output. I don't want to change the original text2.txt. How would you do that? Also, where did you look for the PATTERN? Kindly explain.

Comment: @Hitch: You must redirect the output. I did an example, look at my code and replace the word I used as pattern with yours.

Answer (score 0):

You're opening your output file in *write* mode, then trying to read from it.  This won't do very much.

Try this:

```
#!/usr/local/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
my $m;
my $filename = "test1.txt";
my $filename1 = "test2.txt";
undef $/;
open(WPR,"<",$filename);
$m=<WPR>;
close(WPR);
open(FPR,"<",$filename1);
my $input = <FPR>;
close(FPR);
$input =~ s/PATTERN/$m;
open(OUT,">",$filename1);
print OUT $input;
close OUT;
```